# Linear model intuition - why can we treat our explanatory variables as deterministic?

Tags: statistics

I'm struggling to understand why, if you have a linear model, say $Y_i = \beta_1 + \beta_2 X_i + \epsilon_i$ , the $Y_i$s can be random and have a distribution, but the $X_i$'s are not. For example if you're modelling height of 10-12 year old girls with an explanatory variable of weight, obviously weight is going to have some sort of distribution among your population. This is quite a big thing to ignore, is it not, when modelling?

Comment: There are two issues: uncertainty in the measurement of weights (and heights); and heights not being determined by weights (correlation rather than causation).  In effect you ignore the first point, and then take the weight of a new girl to consider the distribution of heights associated with that weight.  Her weight is what it is, and so for predicting her height it is not a random variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the $x_i$ in a regression have to be considered as random, but
in the simplest cases they are not.

If you are planning an experiment to see the response (perhaps decreased
blood pressure, or decreased count of a type of bacteria in the blood) $Y_i$
that results from giving specific doses $x_i$ of a drug.

Then the experiment will be planned to give subjects carefully measured,
non-random, doses $x_i.$ These are planned in advance and known. In simple
linear regression, the resulting response for a particular subject is
$Y_i = \beta_9 + \beta_1 x_i + e_i,$ where $e_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim}
\mathsf{N}(0, \sigma^2),$ and the $\beta_i$ and $\sigma^2$ are to be estimated.
Then $Y_i$ are clearly random variables. Estimates $\hat \beta_0, \hat \beta_1,$
and $\hat {\sigma^2}$ are also random variables derived from the $n$ data pairs $(x_i, Y_i).$

Comment: So the $x_i$'s don't have a distribution because they're chosen for the experiment?

Comment: That's the _assumption._ Of course you have to know (or check to see whether) it's really true. If you're trying to see if father's heights have predictive power for son's heights, then both father's height x and son's height y might be random. (If x is random, it's sometimes called 'error-in-variables' regression, as I recall.)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help - it's a lot clearer now.